# Fill a 3d array with stream in java

Tags: arrays, java-8, java-stream

My current code is like:

```
double[][][] result = new double[1000][][];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
   result[i] = somemethod();
}
```

Now I want to use stream to do the same thing. I did a lot of research, but cannot find an answer to fill the first dimension with the return value of another method.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: what's your `somemethod` doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your task, the 3D nature of the array is irrelevant. You can replace `double[][]` with `X` in your mind and follow the same generic steps, you would do when producing the array `X[]`:

```
X[] array = IntStream.range(0, size).mapToObj(i -> somemethod()).toArray(X[]::new);
```

Using `double[][]` for `X` and `1000` for `size` yields:

```
double[][][] result
    = IntStream.range(0, 1000).mapToObj(i -> somemethod()).toArray(double[][][]::new);
```

If `somemethod()` is expensive, but has no interference (so multiple concurrent calls are safe), you can use `.parallel()` with the stream. You could also use

```
double[][][] result = new double[1000][][];
Arrays.parallelSetAll(args, i -> somemethod());
```

in that case.

Comment: the `parallelSetAll` don't support if `somemethod` return the result in ordered.

Comment: @holi-java: there is no ordering here, unless `somemethod` modifies shared state behind the scenes. That’s why I said, “If somemethod() … has no interference”. As otherwise, you can’t call it concurrently, so neither, parallel stream nor `parallelSetAll` can be used when it modifies shared state.

Comment: I mean if `somemethod` do something like as an `Iterator`. then `parallelSetAll` will results in unordered  result. Am I right?

Comment: @holi-java: if it works like an `Iterator`, it will modify the `Iterator`’s state when retrieving one element. That’s just a special case of “modifying shared state”, so doesn’t work in parallel, whether you use a stream or `parallelSetAll`. The only correct way to produce an ordered result, is to use the index argument, which the OP’s example code doesn’t. If you use the index, both, parallel streams and `parallelSetAll` will do the right thing.